# How can I send a http delete request from browser?

Tags: javascript, http, http-delete

Is there a way to send a DELETE request from a website, using `xmlhttprequest` or something similar?

Comment: @jldupont: It can be very useful, think about a file manager.

Comment: @jldupont I think they mean from a web page.

Answer (score 29):

As someone mentioned above, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will do this for you, via the following syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "delete_script.php",
    data: "name=someValue",
    success: function(msg){
        alert("Data Deleted: " + msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can test if your browse has DELETE implemented [here](http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/)

Supposing req is a XMLHttpRequest object, the code would be `req.open("DELETE", uri, false)`;

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 7):

I use fetch API on one of the projects:

```
fetch(deleteEndpoint, {
  method: 'delete',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({id: id, token: token})
})
```

I have `deleteEndpoint`, `id` and `token` previously defined.

Comment: This is the simplest and most modern answer.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with [`jQuery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options), if you don't mind the dependence on a framework.  I believe `jQuery` uses `XmlHttpRequest` to perform this action.  You'd use the `$.ajax` function with the `type` parameter set to `DELETE`.

Please note that not all browsers support HTTP DELETE requests.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both PUT and DELETE are not implemented (in the case of Prototype) due to flaky browser support.

Answer (score -3):

You can use php to do this:

setup your XMLHTTPRequst to call a phpscript that deletes a named file, and then pass the filename that you intend to be removed to the php script and let it do its business.