# Remove perms from iframe app using JavaScript SDK/Graph API?

Tags: javascript, sdk, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook JavaScript SDK (on Graph API) is it possible to revoke special permissions programmatically that have been allowed to your app by the user (e.g. post to wall, see friends, etc?), or must the user manually administer their privacy settings to remove/deny those permissions to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to do using the new Graph API. However, you can do it using the legacy API.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeauthorization/

```
  <a href="#" id="fb_disconnect">Disconnect me!</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#fb_disconnect").click(function(){
        FB.api({ method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' }, function(response) {})
        return false;
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can revoke individual permissions with the graph API like so:

HTTP DELETE -> https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?permission=[PERMISSION NAME]

You mentioned that you are using the API with JavaScript - this thread discusses how to send a HTTP DELETE with JavaScript:

[http delete request from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908693/http-delete-request-from-browser)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly related to your question, but another plausible solution is to open a new tab in the user's browser with the page of application in use:

http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications&app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

There he can select the permission he wants to revoke.