# Calling DELETE method in Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

In a new Web API project with :

- **`GET` method**

  ```
  // GET api/values/5
  public string Get(int id)
  {
      return "value";
   }
  ```
- **`DELETE` method**

  ```
  // DELETE api/values/5
  public void Delete(int id)
  {
      var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
      var server = client.GetServer();
      var db = server.GetDatabase("Test");
      var collection = db.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities");
      var deleteEntity = Query<Entity>.EQ(e => e.Id, id);
      collection.Remove(deleteEntity);        
  }
  ```

They have a similar URL: `api/values/5`.

When I want to call the `Delete` method, it executes the `Get` method. What do I do?

Comment: Do you call it using the HTTP Verb "DELETE"? Can you describe how you request your API?

Comment: Please show how you are calling Delete method? Also have you correctly decorated methods with proper attributes?

Comment: This is my delete method.

Comment: @Tanvir: show how you call it.

Comment: http://localhost:10746/api/values/4

I call this.

Comment: And how does that perform a `DELETE` call?

Comment: So, how will I call DELETE method? I am a beginner at Web API. 
@Jeroen Vannevel

Comment: Where is the actual code calling the delete method? Do you have a `form`? Something else?

Answer (score 6):

The URL is the same but you invoke this URL programaticaly with a "DELETE" 'http method' rather than "GET".  If you are just navigating to the URL in your browser, the browser will only do a GET.  How you programmatically do a DELETE (or POST or PUT) will depend on what library you are using to invoke the service but they all tend to have some kind of parameter or property called 'method' for setting this.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `HttpDelete` attribute:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpdeleteattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

You need to decorate your methods like this so that MVC knows how to handle the incoming request:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get(int id)
{
    ...
}

[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

If you're submitting to the delete method via an HTML form, bear in mind they only support the POST and GET methods, so you'll need to submit the DELETE via JavaScript:

[http delete request from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908693/http-delete-request-from-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Use...

Get: /controller/123456

Delete: /controller/id/123456

Answer (score 0):

The config piece below solved my problem:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />

  <!--This will enable all Web API verbose-->
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```