# Ask server to delete record

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest

I'm pretty new to web development, so bear with me. I've also simplified the code to try to get the best answer.

```
<a href="/item/1">Item</a>
<img src="x.png" alt="Delete">
```

Basically, if someone clicks "Item" they get taken to /item/1. If they click the img x.png, it should ask the server to delete /item/1.

Obviously nothing is going to happen if I click x.png with the code as it is, but that's the big question:

I can make my web server recognize the DELETE method for /item/:id, but how do I submit DELETE from a browser? If I can't that makes POST or GET as the only options.

Wrapping the img around a href=... would be easy, but that only does a GET and would break RESTfulness, so it looks like I need to use POST. How can I do this cleanly?

Second question:

I'm assuming I would also have to refresh the page after submitting the delete to get fresh data. Is there a way to avoid this?

HTML, JavaScript, JQuery answers are all welcome.

Comment: Use Ajax if you do not want your web page to refresh after POST

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http delete request from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908693/http-delete-request-from-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery ajax

Lets say

### Method 1

```
<a href="/item/1" class="delete_anchor">Item</a>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".delete_anchor").click(function(e)
    {
         e.preventDefault();
         var url = $(this).attr('href');
          $.ajax(
          {
             url: url,
             method: 'POST',
             success: function()
             {
                 alert("done");
             }
          });
     });
});
```

### Method 2

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="delete_anchor">Item</a>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".delete_anchor").click(function(e)
    {
         e.preventDefault();
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
          $.ajax(
          {
             url: '/item/,
             data: {"id":id},
             method: 'POST',
             success: function()
             {
                 alert("done");
             }
          });
     });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Couple comments: to keep with restful practices, I changed method to 'DELETE' instead of 'POST', added error: function(), so I can capture the error, and used  window.location.reload() in success to refresh the page so the deleted item goes away.

Comment: Perfect! Glad to help you mate :D

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is part of database management's most basic activities, aka CRUD (Create Read Update Delete).

I recommend that you use a tool like [PHP Scaffold](http://www.phpscaffold.com/) which will create the basic code* for you.  Using `phpmyadmin` export your table's structure and copy that (for example):

```
CREATE TABLE `phone` (
  `Id_Phone` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ds_Phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nr_Phone_Country_Code` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '55',
  `Nr_Phone_Area_Code` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '11',
  `Nr_Phone_Number` int(10) NOT NULL
)
```

You must have file with your database connection info (PHP Scaffold will place the include for you)

```
<?php 
$username = "who"; // your username
$password = "aPassword"; // yor password
$database = "mydbName"; // your db name
$server = "localhost";  // leave this

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Instead of copying this in your code, save this file (i called it `ConnDB.php` and include it at the beginning of each new php page - if you use a tool like the one above, it will do it for you)

```
include ('ConnDB.php');
```

- Examine the code and you will find the answers to your doubts.  Play around with it, include selects and populate them from your db.  Have fun.