# Python flask DELETE request

Tags: python, flask

I'm in the middle of developing a Python app and using flask, and this is my DELETE function:

```
@app.route('/DeleteMessage', methods=['DELETE'])
def DeleteMessage():
    messages = Message.query.all()
    application_id = request.args.get('application_id')
    if application_id:
        messages.filter_by(user_id=application_id)
    session_id = request.args.get('session_id')
    if session_id:
        messages.filter_by(session_id=session_id)    
    message_id = request.args.get('message_id')
    if message_id:
        messages = message.filter_by(message_id=message_id)  
    db.session.delete(messages)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'ok'
```

When I try to run it, it sends me such an error message:

```
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

Comment: Please show how you make a request.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/DeleteMessage?message_id=1

Comment: How are you sending the request? From javascript? Are you setting the delete http method type?

Comment: I'm only developing the server side, so I'm currently running this function by typing:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/DeleteMessage?applicationId=1
Into the search bar in my browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers support PUT and DELETE only with AJAX request, but not with HTML form submission. HTML form tag will allow only **GET** and **POST** methods.

In your case, you can send an ajax request like this,

```
$.ajax({
url: '{{url_for("DeleteMessage")}}',
type: 'DELETE',
success: function(result) {
    // write something if needed
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You make GET request, but your flask backend awaiting DELETE request on that endpoint `/DeleteMessage`. You can change request method to GET `@app.route('/DeleteMessage', methods=['GET'])` and it will work, but it is contrary to the http standard.

You can read about how to send DELETE request in this question: [How to send DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908693/how-can-i-send-a-http-delete-request-from-browser)

Additional Information:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3
https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: I tried:
@ app.route ('/ DeleteMessage', methods = ['GET'])
But I received such an error message:
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery' is not mapped

Comment: Please, update the question and include code for your models and db engine.

Comment: Be wary of this implementation, implementing state-changing operations as a GET request will make your application vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgery